# How to pass a custom hook as props and retain parent context?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a created a custom formatting hook like so:

```
const useFormatter = (value, short = false) => {
  if (isNaN(value ?? undefined) || !isFinite(value)) {
    return "";
  }
  if (aggregator === Aggregator.TOTAL) {
    const prefix = metric !== Metric.USAGE ? getCurrencySymbol(currency) : "";
    if (short) {
      return prefix + formatNumber(value, 2);
    } else {
      return prefix + formatDecimalNumber(value, 2, 0);
    }
  } else if (aggregator === Aggregator.TOTAL_OVER_TOTAL) {
    let suffix = "";
    let prefix = "";
    switch (metric) {
      case Metric.COST:
        // Cost/Usage
        prefix = "$";
        break;
      case Metric.SAVINGS:
        // Savings/Cost
        suffix = "%";
        value = (1 - 1 / (value + 1)) * 100;
        break;
      default:
    }

    const d = value % 1;
    let minFracDigits = 2;
    if (d < 9e-5) {
      minFracDigits = 6;
    } else if (d < 9e-4) {
      minFracDigits = 5;
    } else if (d < 9e-3) {
      minFracDigits = 4;
    } else if (d < 9e-2) {
      minFracDigits = 3;
    }
    return `${prefix}${formatDecimalNumber(value, minFracDigits, 0)}${suffix}`;
  } else {
    const suffix = "%";
    return formatDecimalNumber(value * 100, 2, 0) + suffix;
  }
};

export default useFormatter;
```

All this is, is shared logic for formatting a number, then I import the hook into a *parent* component and use like so:

```
const formatter = React.useCallback(
    useFormatter(value, short = false),
      [aggregator, currency, metric]
    );
```

It is then passed down to a child in the `props` where the `value` and `short` (optional) params are given to it, the reason for this setup is to maintain the parent context and then pass it down essentially as a callback. Unfortunately this code does not compile and I don't understand why, the error I am getting is:

```
./src/Components/Dashboard/test_comp.js
  Line 88:18:  'value' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 88:25:  'short' is not defined  no-undef
```

Now in the child component it *is* being given these values, but clearly I am missing something here. Why does my code not compile?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect, you are passing result of invocation, not a fn, to `useCallback`, please try this:

```
const formatter = React.useCallback(
    // we are passing fn here, not invocation result
    () => useFormatter(value, short = false),
    [aggregator, currency, metric]
);
```

You should also rename your custom fn, from `useFormatter` to something different for ability to use it as plain function. Seems React detects `useXxx` pattern and force Hooks rules for such functions.

Comment: When I do that I get this error:
`React Hook "useFormatter" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` besides I don't understand I am passing a function not an invocation, in fact it's the same function, why is it invoked?

Comment: I've updated the answer, seems React detects fn names by "useX" pattern and force its hooks rules for such fn.

Comment: When I do this I am getting the same original error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem with this code is that you treat it as a custom hook while it is a plain function.

One would choose to write a custom hook, when the logic needs access to other hooks. You are not using any hooks inside your function, therefore make it a plain function and do not use the hook naming convention. Furthermore udalmik is right by saying that you are passing the result of the invocation rather than the function.

From the React docs:

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.